# Why isn't fromfile-prefix-chars in Python argparse working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to use the fromfile-prefix-chars feature of argparse in Python to load all my command line arguments from a file, but it keeps complaining that I haven't specified some argument.

The code:

```
import argparse

def go():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
   parser.add_argument("--option1")
   parser.add_argument("--option2", type=int, required=True)
   args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    go()
```

The argument file:

```
--option1 foo
--option2 1234
```

The command line and output:

```
$ python testargparse.py @testargs
usage: testargparse.py [-h] [--option1 OPTION1] --option2 OPTION2
testargparse.py: error: argument --option2 is required
```

You can see that I'm providing the required argument in the file, but argparse isn't seeing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that, when specified in a file, each argument must have an '=' between it and the option name.  While argparse is somewhat more flexible on that format when run from the command line (where space or = is ok), when run from the file it must have an '='.

So, a working argument file would be:

```
--option1=foo
--option2=1234
```

Something else to be aware of, be sure you don't have any extra whitespace at the end of the lines or that whitespace will get included with the option when argparse reads the file.

Answer (score 11):

From the documentation:

> Arguments read from a file must by default be one per line ... and are treated as if they were in the same place as the original file referencing argument on the command line. So in the example above, the expression ['-f', 'foo', '@args.txt'] is considered equivalent to the expression ['-f', 'foo', '-f', 'bar'].

In the example:

```
fp.write('-f\nbar')
```

So the file contains:

```
-f
bar
```

In other words, each of the file lines corresponds to one 'word' (blank separated) in the command line.  `--option1=foo` is one word.  `--option1 foo` is interpreted just as though it was quoted in the command line,eg. `prog.py '--option1 foo' '--option2 1234'`

The https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args has a custom function that will split lines on spaces.  Experiment with that if you want to stick with the argument file.

---

```
import argparse

with open('args.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('--option1 foo\n--option2 1234')  # error
    # but works with modifed 'convert...'
    #fp.write('--option1=foo\n--option2=1234')  # works
    #fp.write('--option1\nfoo\n--option2\n1234') # works

def convert_arg_line_to_args(arg_line):
    for arg in arg_line.split():
        if not arg.strip():
            continue
        yield arg
"""
default line converter:
def convert_arg_line_to_args(self, arg_line):
    return [arg_line]
"""

def go():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
   parser.convert_arg_line_to_args = convert_arg_line_to_args
   parser.add_argument("--option1")
   parser.add_argument("--option2", type=int, required=True)
   args = parser.parse_args(['@args.txt'])
   print args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    go()
```

---

`@toes` suggested using `shlex` to parse the file.  `shlex` has a nice feature in that it strips of unnecessary quotes.

`shlex` can be used to split individual lines of the file.

```
def sh_split(arg_line):
    for arg in shlex.split(arg_line):
        yield arg
parser.convert_arg_line_to_args = sh_split
```

Or it can replace the whole @file read method (`_read_args_from_files`)- this should function the same as `@toes` answer, except that the `@file` string can be anywhere in the commandline (or even be repeated).

```
def at_read_fn(arg_strings):
    # expand arguments referencing files
    new_arg_strings = []
    for arg_string in arg_strings:
        if not arg_string or not arg_string.startswith('@'):
            new_arg_strings.append(arg_string)
        else:
            with open(arg_string[1:]) as args_file:
                arg_strings = shlex.split(args_file.read())
                new_arg_strings.extend(arg_strings)
    return new_arg_strings
parser._read_args_from_files = at_read_fn
```

Obviously a cleaner production version would modify these methods in an `ArgumentParser` subclass.

Comment: I appreciate the detail in this answer, but I think it's overkill for the user that just wants their argument file to work. I think it should highlight that the easiest solution is to just add an '=' to the file.  If you combine my answer with yours (with the easy solution up front), I think it would be better and would accept it.

Comment: A possible problem with the documentation is the ambiguity in the meaning of 'argument'.  You may have been thinking of `--option1 foo` as one argument, or optional+argument.  But what the doc really means is `argument string`, the strings that `argv` is divided into.  Effectively the strings from the file are inserted into `argv` before any real parsing begins.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a better answer to this: use shlex.

```
if sys.argv[1].startswith('@'):
    args = parser.parse_args( shlex.split(open(sys.argv[1][1:]).read()) )
else:
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

This allows you to specify args in a file in a more natural way e.g., it allows using spaces *or* equals sign to specify your args on a single line as in:

```
arg1
arg2
--opt1 'foo'
--opt2='bar'
```

shlex.split splits this as you would expect:

```
['arg1', 'arg2', '--opt1', 'foo', '--opt2=bar']
```

The only thing this method doesn't have is that it expects the @file.txt to be the first argument.

Comment: You could probably combine this `shlex.split` with the `convert_arg_line_to_args` method I describe.   That will splice in the values whereever the `@` string occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way

```
# encoding: utf-8
import imp
import argparse


class LoadConfigAction(argparse._StoreAction):
    NIL = object()

    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(option_strings, dest)
        self.help = "Load configuration from file"

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        super(LoadConfigAction, self).__call__(parser, namespace, values, option_string)

        config = imp.load_source('config', values)

        for key in (set(map(lambda x: x.dest, parser._actions)) & set(dir(config))):
            setattr(namespace, key, getattr(config, key))
```

Usage

```
parser.add_argument("-C", "--config", action=LoadConfigAction, default=None)
parser.add_argument("-H", "--host")
```

Example config (real is python file)

```
# Config example /etc/my.conf
import os

# Parameter definition
host = os.getenv("HOST", "127.0.0.1")
```