# Saving python argparse file

Tags: python, argparse

Argparse has a feature that called [`fromfile-prefix-chars`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars), that seems to do exactly half of what I am looking for. How can I create the file for this feature from the current command line arguments?

I have a complicated script with a parser that is automating part of a code build.  The use-case is setting up the command line correctly the first time, and then basically re-running with the same arguments.

Using a file and loading from that seems like a great way to implement what I need.  What seems to be missing is a simple way of writing out the initial command line to a file so the existing file parsing will work correctly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The file format is documented quite clearly:

> Arguments read from a file must by default be one per line [...]

and the code example in the documentation shows that they write a file with newlines in between:

> ```
> >>> with open('args.txt', 'w') as fp:
> ...     fp.write('-f\nbar')
> ```

If you want to save your current command line, just write `sys.argv[1:]` to a file, with newlines between the arguments:

```
with open('commandline_args.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from argparse import ArgumentParser
>>> import sys
>>> parser = ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='?')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='bar', nargs='?', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> sys.argv[1:] = ['--foo', 'spam', 'barbaz']
>>> parser.parse_args()
Namespace(bar='barbaz', foo='spam')
>>> with open('commandline_args.txt', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('\n'.join(sys.argv[1:]))
...
17
>>> parser.parse_args(['@commandline_args.txt'])
Namespace(bar='barbaz', foo='spam')
>>> sys.argv[1:] = ['--foo=spam', 'barbaz']  # using alternate syntax
>>> parser.parse_args()
Namespace(bar='barbaz', foo='spam')
>>> with open('commandline_args.txt', 'w') as f:
...     f.write('\n'.join(sys.argv[1:]))
...
17
>>> parser.parse_args(['@commandline_args.txt'])
Namespace(bar='barbaz', foo='spam')
```

Comment: I don't think it is that simple.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25084994/169296.  Your solution would split the flag and the value for the flag into two separate lines.

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: yes, and that's fine. Note that the code example in the documentation does **exactly that**.

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: note they are separate argument entries in `sys.argv` too. You'd either have `'--option=foo'` (one string` or `'--option'` and `'foo'` in the `sys.argv` list.

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: last but not least, note that the question you link to the file was **not** split into separate lines. The question would have worked if `--option1` and `foo` are on separate lines *or* you use `=` between the switch and the value.

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: I added a demo session showing both forms.

Answer (score 27):

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import json

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=8)
parser.add_argument('--resume', type=str, default='a/b/c.ckpt')
parser.add_argument('--surgery', type=str, default='190', choices=['190', '417'])
args = parser.parse_args()

with open('commandline_args.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(args.__dict__, f, indent=2)

parser = ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()
with open('commandline_args.txt', 'r') as f:
    args.__dict__ = json.load(f)

print(args)
```