# Loading command line arguments as file while enforcing required args

Tags: python, argparse

I am working on a project with many command line arguments and I'd like to be able to specify all of the arguments in the form of a file (i.e. JSON), and load this file into an `argparse` object, instead of pasting them into the terminal every time. I also need to enforce the presence of required arguments. I've found a couple options but none of them do exactly what I need.

If I have something like this

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--image_path", type=str, required=True)     
parser.add_argument("--count", type=int, required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

One approach might be to add something like this to update the dictionary with the JSON contents

```
args_dict = vars(args)
with open('path/to/args.json', 'rb') as f:
    args_dict.update(json.load(f))
```

But an error occurs at the `parse_args()` line, since it didn't see the required arguments passed in.

The other approach I considered is to use

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
```

and just pass the file name, prefixed with @, to the command. The problem here is that I have to convert the dictionary-like format (JSON) to a line-separated list of arguments, as noted in the documentation. This is not trivial in my case.

I also considered just saving the arguments as a line-separated list to begin with, but the way that I know how to do that involves iterating over `sys.argv` and printing to a text file, which is problematic because I have some args that are assigned default values, which are not represented in `sys.argv`. I need to record the default values that were used for later reference.

It seems like there should be a simple way to do this, but I'm stumped at the moment.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084993/why-isnt-fromfile-prefix-chars-in-python-argparse-working) help? I'm not sure why you specifically want the file to be in a JSON format

Comment: maybe something with [parents parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parents)

Comment: If you define appropriate defaults you won't care whether they've been provided or not.  Or after all the parsing and `json` load, check for arguments with a `None` value (the base default).  Nothing in `argparse` itself will solve your problem.

Comment: `parse_args()` puts default values in the namespace at the start of parsing.  When an Action is handled, the new value is written to the namespace, and a reference is added to "seen" list.  At the end of parsing, it checks if all "required" Actions have been "seen", and raises the error if not.  So don't set the "required" flag if you don't want such a error.

Comment: I want it in JSON format, or anything dict-like, because at the end of my program, I save the arguments from `opt.__dict__` into a file so that I can reuse it or refer later to which arguments were used for this particular run. We are doing many experiments so keeping logs is important.